# Getting IPV4 address from a sockaddr structure

Tags: c, ip-address

How can I extract an IP address into a string? I can't find a reference that tells me how `char sa_data[14]` is encoded.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Once `sockaddr` cast to `sockaddr_in`, it becomes this:

```
struct sockaddr_in {
    u_short     sin_family;
    u_short     sin_port;
    struct      in_addr sin_addr;
    char        sin_zero[8];
};
```

Comment: This is a bit less than what you need to format as a string.

Comment: How can we ensure that the casting is safe?

Comment: @eonil the first member of all `sockaddr` is a `u_short` type tag.

Answer (score 71):

Just cast the entire `sockaddr` structure to a [sockaddr_in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740496%28VS.85%29.aspx). Then you can use:

```
char *ip = inet_ntoa(their_addr.sin_addr)
```

To retrieve the standard ip representation.

Comment: +1. Depending on platform, remember to check the family first. There may not be an IPV4 address to extract...

Comment: @SteveJessop How do we do the check btw? Is there any example code or something to look for?

Comment: `if (their_sockaddr_ptr->sa_family == AF_INET) { struct sockaddr_in *their_inaddr_ptr = (struct sockaddr_in *)their_sockaddr_ptr; } else { /* not an IPv4 address */ }`, or similar.

Comment: @Emil How do you cast the entire sockaddr structure to sockaddr_in?
Able to give an example? :D

Comment: @mister If you have a question, start question, that's what SO is here for. Questions are first class citizen on SO. And the answer is, just cast it! `sockaddr` is only an "abstract" address, no address really ever is of that type, it just defines the common fields all socketaddr structs must have. `struct sockaddr * saddr = ...; if (saddr->sa_family == AF_INET) { struct sockaddr_in * saddr_in = (sockaddr_in *)saddr; ... }`

Answer (score 43):

`inet_ntoa()` works for IPv4; `inet_ntop()` works for both IPv4 and IPv6.

Given an input `struct sockaddr *res`, here are two snippets of code (tested on macOS):

### Using inet_ntoa()

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>

struct sockaddr_in *addr_in = (struct sockaddr_in *)res;
char *s = inet_ntoa(addr_in->sin_addr);
printf("IP address: %s\n", s);
```

### Using inet_ntop()

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// obviously INET6_ADDRSTRLEN is expected to be larger
// than INET_ADDRSTRLEN, but this may be required in case
// if for some unexpected reason IPv6 is not supported, and
// INET6_ADDRSTRLEN is defined as 0
// but this is not very likely and I am aware of no cases of
// this in practice (editor)
char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN > INET_ADDRSTRLEN ? INET6_ADDRSTRLEN : INET_ADDRSTRLEN]
    = '\0';

switch(res->sa_family) {
    case AF_INET: {
        struct sockaddr_in *addr_in = (struct sockaddr_in *)res;

        ////char s[INET_ADDRSTRLEN] = '\0';
            // this is large enough to include terminating null

        inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(addr_in->sin_addr), s, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
        break;
    }
    case AF_INET6: {
        struct sockaddr_in6 *addr_in6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)res;
        
        ////char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN] = '\0';
            // not sure if large enough to include terminating null?

        inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(addr_in6->sin6_addr), s, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
        break;
    }
    default:
        break;
}
printf("IP address: %s\n", s);
```

Comment: in which header?

Comment: #include <arpa/inet.h>

Comment: Not sure why you're using malloc and free here, a static buffer would be the more appropriate solution.

Answer (score 37):

Emil's answer is correct, but it's my understanding that `inet_ntoa` is deprecated and that instead you should use `inet_ntop`. If you are using IPv4, cast your `struct sockaddr` to `sockaddr_in`. Your code will look something like this:

```
struct addrinfo *res;   // populated elsewhere in your code
struct sockaddr_in *ipv4 = (struct sockaddr_in *)res->ai_addr;
char ipAddress[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(ipv4->sin_addr), ipAddress, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);

printf("The IP address is: %s\n", ipAddress);
```

Take a look at [this great resource](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/inet_ntopman.html) for more explanation, including how to do this for IPv6 addresses.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `getnameinfo` [for Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738532%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [for Linux](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getnameinfo).

Assuming you have a good (i.e. it's members have appropriate values) `sockaddr*` called `pSockaddr`:

```
char clienthost[NI_MAXHOST];  //The clienthost will hold the IP address.
char clientservice[NI_MAXSERV];
int theErrorCode = getnameinfo(pSockaddr, sizeof(*pSockaddr), clienthost, sizeof(clienthost), clientservice, sizeof(clientservice), NI_NUMERICHOST|NI_NUMERICSERV);

if( theErrorCode != 0 )
{
    //There was an error.
    cout << gai_strerror(e1) << endl;
}else{
    //Print the info.
    cout << "The ip address is = " << clienthost << endl;
    cout << "The clientservice = " << clientservice << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following program resolves a given domain:

```
$ gcc a.c

$ ./a.out google.com
AF_INET: 216.58.214.238
AF_INET6: 2a00:1450:400d:803::200e

$ ./a.out google.com af_inet
AF_INET: 216.58.214.238
```

`a.c`:

```
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct addrinfo hints, *res, *cres;
    int r;
    char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    if (argc > 2)
        hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;

    r = getaddrinfo(argv[1], NULL, &hints, &res);
    if (r) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(r));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (cres = res; cres; cres = cres->ai_next) {
        switch (cres->ai_family) {
        case AF_INET:
            inet_ntop(AF_INET, &((struct sockaddr_in *)cres->ai_addr)->sin_addr, s, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
            printf("AF_INET: %s\n", s);
            break;
        case AF_INET6:
            inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &((struct sockaddr_in6 *)cres->ai_addr)->sin6_addr, s, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
            printf("AF_INET6: %s\n", s);
            break;
        }
    }

    freeaddrinfo(res);
}
```

Another example can be found [here](https://man.archlinux.org/man/inet_pton.3.en).

Answer (score 0):

Type casting of `sockaddr` to `sockaddr_in` and retrieval of ipv4 using `inet_ntoa`

```
char * ip = inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)sockaddr)->sin_addr);
```