# sockaddr - print all information which sa_data holds - c++

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

in my c++ application I' using sockaddr. I want to see all the infarmation which sockaddr.sa_data[14] holds. for now I just print the ip from sa_data[2].sa_data[3].sa_data[4].sa_data[5].

I want to print in a way that I can understand (and please explain) all the information in the sa_data 14 bytes.

any help?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility would be to use [`inet_ntop`](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/inet_ntopman.html) which should be able to handle IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.  It will produce a human-readable string with the address.

Answer (score 5):

In the sa_data member, for IPv4 on Windows, I have found that the first two bytes hold the port number, and the next four hold the IP address.

For example, if I resolve the address `228.0.0.1:9995`, the sa_data member is...

```
27 0b e4 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Here, `270b` is the Hex value representation of 9995 in the first two bytes. The next four bytes are the IP address, where `0xe4` is 228, then two zeros, then `0x01`, or 228 0 0 1.
The last eight bytes are unused, which tallies with the comment above about only the first six bytes being used.

Note that sa_data will vary in format with the protocol being used.

Answer (score 1):

the value of the sa_data which is 14 bytes is changed(are different) based on the address family : sa_family.

1. if the the address family is AF_INET the first two bytes are port number and the next 4 bytes will be the source ip address.
2. if the the address family is PF_PACKET the first two bytes tells the Ethernet type(wither 0800--> IP, 0806 --> ARP etc..) and the next 4 bytes (actually the first one is enough) it tells the source interface. if the value is:

   - 02 00 00 00 = eth0,
   - 03 00 00 00 = eth1,
   - 04 00 00 00 = eth2 etc ... and 
     the last 8 bytes are unused in AF_INET family but in the PF_PACKET i didn't find out.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::copy( &sa_data[0], &sa_data[0]+sizeof(sa_data)/sizeof(sa_data[0]), 
             std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
```

will print each element as an int with a space separating. You can also use unsigned int if you don't want negative values and you can iomanip your stream to print hex if you prefer that.

Answer (score 0):

The information in `sockaddr` depends on what socket family and protocol you're using.

If you're using IPv4, the right thing is to cast the `sockaddr` pointer to [`sockaddr_in *`](http://www.umiacs.com/sockaddr_inman.html). Only the first 6 bytes of the address are meaningful when you're using IPv4. The rest should just be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

To get and print the `sa_data member` of the `struct sockaddr` please refer to John's answer at [Getting IPV4 address from a sockaddr structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276294/getting-ipv4-address-from-a-sockaddr-structure)