# how do you cast sockaddr structure to a sockaddr_in - C++ networking sockets ubuntu UDP

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, ubuntu, client

I am trying to get the client address, but i am unsure how do i cast the sockaddr structure to sockaddr_in?

```
struct sockaddr_in cliAddr, servAddr;

    n = recvfrom(sd, msg, MAX_MSG, 0,(struct sockaddr *) cliAddr,sizeof(cliAddr));

 //i tried this but it does not work
    struct sockaddr cliSockAddr = (struct sockaddr *) cliAddr; 
    char *ip = inet_ntoa(cliSockAddr.sin_addr);
```

Thanks in advance! :)

---

i've found questions that brought me to this step:
[Getting IPV4 address from a sockaddr structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276294/getting-ipv4-address-from-a-sockaddr-structure)

---

Sorry to avoid confusion, this is my real implementation where "ci" is an object to store pointers such as sockaddr_in.

```
    /* receive message */
    n = recvfrom(*(ci->getSd()), msg, MAX_MSG, 0,(struct sockaddr *) ci->getCliAddr(),ci->getCliLen());

    char *ip = inet_ntoa(ci->getCliAddr().sin_addr);
```

i will get the following errors:

```
udpserv.cpp:166: error: request for member ‘sin_addr’ in ‘ci->clientInfo::getCliAddr()’, which is of non-class type ‘sockaddr_in*’
```

Comment: Your code won't even compile. You are assigning a pointer to a structure, declare `cliSockAddr` as a pointer.

Comment: What you are really asking is the reverse of what it says in your title.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I would point out that if this is actually C++ the idiomatic way to do this would be:

```
sockaddr *sa = ...; // struct not needed in C++
char ip[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN] = {0};

switch (sa->sa_family) {
  case AF_INET: {
    // use of reinterpret_cast preferred to C style cast
    sockaddr_in *sin = reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_in*>(sa);
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &sin->sin_addr, ip, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
    break;
  }
  case AF_INET6: {
    sockaddr_in6 *sin = reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_in6*>(sa);
    // inet_ntoa should be considered deprecated
    inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &sin->sin6_addr, ip, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
    break;
  }
  default:
    abort();
}
```

This sample code handles IPv4 and IPv6 addresses and also would be considered more C++ idiomatic than either of the suggested implementations.

Comment: I really like that you've used reinterpret_cast.  It makes everything so much cleaner, and less pointers need to be used.  On a side note, I didn't set sa as a pointer to begin with. I simply passed the address to it in via reference in like this (mine is a school project and only using IPv4 -- inet_ntoa(reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_in*>(&clientIpAddress)->sin_addr)

Answer (score 17):

It is actually very simple!

```
struct sockaddr *sa = ...;

if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET)
{
    struct sockaddr_in *sin = (struct sockaddr_in *) sa;
    ip = inet_ntoa(sin->sin_addr);
}
```

Comment: And while you're doing that, make your program IPv6 capable by checking for AF_INET6 too. ;)

Comment: I know this is an old thread but for sake of correctness, @bmatheny's answer below is the correct one since this question is tagged "C++". `reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_in*>(sa)` is the right way to convert the two types and though the old C conversion still works, it is too obscure and won't let clear the intentions for any reader.

Answer (score 3):

I think this will compile just fine for you and do what you want.

```
struct sockaddr_in cliAddr={}, servAddr={};

socklen_t cliAddrLength = sizeof(cliAddr);

n = recvfrom(sd, msg, MAX_MSG, 0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliAddr, &cliAddrLength);
```