# Convert IP address from sockaddr to in_addr

Tags: c++, sockets, visual-c++

I need to convert socket address that is placed in structure `sockaddr` to structure `in_addr`. I was trying to understand how IP is stored in these structures:

```
struct sockaddr
{
    u_short sa_family;      /* address family */
    char    sa_data[14];    /* up to 14 bytes of direct address */
};


struct in_addr 
{
    union
    {
        struct { u_char s_b1,s_b2,s_b3,s_b4; } S_un_b;
        struct { u_short s_w1,s_w2; } S_un_w;
        u_long S_addr;
    }
    S_un;
};
```

I got stuck with question how `127.0.0.1` is stored in 14 characters of `sa_data`.
What is the best way to convert sockaddr to in_addr?

Comment: This question talks about the encoding - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276294/getting-ipv4-address-from-a-sockaddr-structure

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`sockaddr` is a generic struct, which is shared by different types of sockets. For TCP/IP sockets this struct becomes `sockaddr_in` (IPv4) or `sockaddr_in6` (IPv6). For unix sockets it becomes `sockaddr_un`.

Ideally you would use `sockaddr_in` instead of `sockaddr`.

But given `sockaddr`, you could do this to extract IP address from it:

```
sockaddr foo;
in_addr ip_address = ((sockaddr_in)foo).sin_addr;
or
in_addr_t ip_address = ((sockaddr_in)foo).sin_addr.s_addr;
```

If you look inside `sockaddr_in` you will see that the first 2 bytes of `sa_data` are the port number. And the next 4 bytes are the IP address.

PS: Please note that the IP address is stored in network byte order, so you will probably need to use `ntohl` (network-to-host) and `htonl` (host-to-network) to convert to/from host byte order.

**UPDATE**

For IPv6 things are similar:

```
sockaddr foo;
in_addr6 ip_address = ((sockaddr_in6)foo).sin6_addr;
```

To access individual bytes, use `ip_address[0]` ... `ip_address[15]`.

Inside the `sockaddr_in6` struct the first 2 bytes of `sa_data` are the port number, next 4 bytes are flow info and after that the next 16 bytes are the IPv6 address.

Bewares, however, that `sockaddr_in6` is **larger** than `sockaddr`, so when casting from `sockaddr` to `sockaddr_in6`, make sure that the address is indeed an IPv6 address by checking the address family `foo.sa_family == AF_INET6`.

Comment: This is what I need. But how to convert when I have IPV6 ?

Comment: @vico, I've updated the answer. Perhaps, you should also update the question, as there was no mention of IPv6 in it. If you are happy with the answer, feel free to accept it.